# Problems with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dropbox

I tried to install dropbox and suddenly it couldn't finish installation.
I tried from the terminal to do it manually and the same,it stucked at 100%.
These are two of the problems are coming through terminal:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock – open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)

E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Also when i tried to do software update is coming this problem:

Software index is broken

It is impossible to install or remove any software. Please use the package manager "Synaptic" or run `sudo apt-get install -f` in a terminal to fix this issue at first.

I tried to fix it but is still the same problem. How can I solve these problems?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Retry after reboot. Use synaptic this time after an update command. Before that, check synaptic for any broken residue package, remove it first. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the lock file which is written while using apt or other installation & update methods to tell the system that an update is installing still exists

Therefor you get the

> Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock

info.

I would check in the first place via

```
ps | grep WHATEVERYOUUSEDTORUNFORMERUPDATE
```

to check if there is still a matching process. In case there isnt give

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

another chance and report back the output if it contains errors

Good luck